# Pyspark : How to applying regex in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to appling regex on **Ident** Column

%15/19%  --> 'S15/19'

%14/11%  --> 'S11/14'

%HPD%  --> 'HPD'

%PTG%  --> 'PTG'

```
+-------------+                                                             
|  Ident      |
+-------------+
|SAS 15/19 USA|
+-------------+
|SHS 14/11 ENG|
+-------------+
|SGS  HPD  FRA|
+-------------+
|SSS  PTG  ALL|
+-------------+
```

```
+-------------+                                                             
|  new_col    |
+-------------+
|    S15/19   |
+-------------+
|    S11/14   |
+-------------+
|    HPD     |
+-------------+
|    PTG     |
+-------------+
```

Comment: do you mean to take the middle value and prefix an "S"?

Comment: No, I mean in all lines that contain PTG = %PTG% for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way, although not pretty since your request is very specific, is to use several [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html) functions:

```
df = (df
 .withColumn('Ident', F.regexp_replace(F.col('Ident'), '.*15\/19.*', 'S15/19'))
 .withColumn('Ident', F.regexp_replace(F.col('Ident'), '.*14\/11.*', 'S14/11'))
 .withColumn('Ident', F.regexp_replace(F.col('Ident'), '.*HPD.*', 'HPD'))
 .withColumn('Ident', F.regexp_replace(F.col('Ident'), '.*PTG.*', 'PTG'))
)
```

You can also use a *for* loop to write the above code in a nicer way:

```
patterns = ['.*15\/19.*', '.*14\/11.*', '.*HPD.*', '.*PTG.*']
replacements = ['S15/19', 'S14/11', 'HPD', 'PTG']

for p, r in zip(patterns, replacements):
  df = df.withColumn('Ident', F.regexp_replace('Ident', p, r))
```

---

```
df.show()
+------+
| Ident|
+------+
|S15/19|
|S14/11|
|   HPD|
|   PTG|
+------+
```